# Why am i getting this error and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, c, cython, sympy

im using anaconda(python2.7) and im in the process of cythonizing a program and im getting an error. where my program writes to the file, i get an attribute error. can someone please help me fix my code? also, any tips to make it run faster(cythonization, ect.) would be greatly appreciated!

this is my code so far:

http://pastebin.com/gmC7rtBB

and this is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e95db2234cf8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/quantum emulator/qemulatortestt.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/quantum emulator')

  File "C:\Users\Jay\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/quantum emulator/qemulatortestt.py", line 246, in <module>
    rewrite(task, asciivalue)

  File "C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/quantum emulator/qemulatortestt.py", line 77, in rewrite
    fle.write(cnt)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: The last line is saying you have a string object (`str`), but the code is trying to call a non-existing `write` method/attribute. It's most likely referencing the `fle` variable.

Comment: even when i remove the line: task = cython.declare(cython.p_char) i get the same error, which is why im confused

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(fle, 'r+') as f:
    f.write(cnt)
    f.close()
    return f
```

`fle` is a string denoting the file path.

Comment: Didn't you see my code? The error is in the line 77 of `qemulatortestt.py`. Take a look at that position and the code above.